# "Error converting data type nvarchar to int."

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis-2008

Using SQL 2008, i was trying to setup an ETL and i run into the error below while running my dtsx package.

Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Error converting data type nvarchar to int.".

The dtsx is running smoothly with SQL 2005. I searched for possible answers through the web but none is helpful. Hope you can share your ideas for this error. Thanks for those who will answer! :)

Comment: I would suggest doing the conversion in the SQL Command of the OLE DB Source or adding a Data Conversion data flow transformation to your Data Flow Task between the OLE DB Source and OLE DB Destination.

Comment: Could you add other informations related to step execution?